# Producer and consumer using kafka and apache camel with embedded topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have written a simple producer and consumer who uses the Kafka and embedded topic that passes test cases.
my question is how can i produce and consume messages with the help of apache camel instead of threads using spring boot that have embedded topic and passes test cases.

so this is my producer:

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducer extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class.getName());

    @Value("${test.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(){
        int producedNumber = new Random().nextInt(100);
        logger.info("Produced number: " + producedNumber);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, String.valueOf(producedNumber));
    }

    public void run(){

        while (true){
            this.sendMessage();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and consumer:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class.getName());

    private Integer sum = 0;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topic}")
    public void receive(String message) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(message);
    }

    public void printResult(){
        logger.info("Sum: " + sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

    public void run(){

        while (true){
            printResult();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

here is my application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: sepehr
test:
  topic: test-topic
```

and testcase:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
public class DemoTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducer producer;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer consumer;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        producer.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        consumer.start();

        consumer.join();
        producer.join();
    }

}
```